# LCH group representation: SOT $\iff$ norm continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, group-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group, $H$ a complex Hilbert space and $\pi : G \to \Bbb{B}(H)^\times$ a group homomorphism from $G$ to the group of invertible bounded linear operators on $H$.

> Assume that $\pi$ is SOT-continuous, meaning that for all $u \in H$ the map $G \to H, x \mapsto \pi(x)u$ is continuous.  Does it follow that $\pi$ is norm continuous, meaning that the map $G \times H \to H, (x,u) \mapsto \pi(x)u$ is continuous?

There seems to be some heated debate whether this holds and under which conditions. Quite amusingly, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/176683/144766) contains two contradictory answers; one adamantly states that it is false, claiming that the left regular representation $$\pi : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{B}(L^2(\Bbb{R}))^\times, \quad (\pi(t)f)(x) := f(x+t), \quad t,x\in \Bbb{R}, f \in L^2(\Bbb{R})$$ is SOT-continuous but not norm continuous. The other answer claims that the statement is true, albeit backing it up only with a dead link.

There is also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2799661/144766), where an answer also claims that the statement is true. Following that approach I came up with the following proof:

Let $V$ be a precompact open neighbourhood of $1$ in $G$. Then for every $u \in H$ the function $\overline{V} \to \Bbb{C}, x \mapsto \pi(x)u$ is continuous on a compact set and hence bounded. In particular,
$$\sup_{x \in V} \|\pi(x)u\| < +\infty$$
so the Uniform boundedness principle implies $C := \sup_{x \in V} \|\pi(x)\| < +\infty$.

Now fix $x_0 \in G$ and $u_0 \in H$. We claim that the map $G \times H \to H, (x,u) \mapsto \pi(x)u$ is continuous at $(x_0,u_0)$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. By assumption, the map $G \to H, x \mapsto \pi(x)u_0$ is continuous at $x_0$ so we can pick an open symmetric neighbourhood $U$ of $1$ in $G$ such that for all $x \in G$ we have
$$x \in x_0U\implies \|\pi(x_0)u_0-\pi(x)u_0\| < \frac\varepsilon2.$$
We can further assume that $U \subseteq V$.

Now assume that $(x,u) \in x_0U \times B\left(u_0, \frac{\varepsilon}{2C\|\pi(x_0)\|}\right)$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\|\pi(x_0)u_0 - \pi(x)u\| &\le \|\pi(x_0)u_0 - \pi(x)u_0\| + \|\pi(x)u_0 - \pi(x)u\| \\
&< \frac\varepsilon2 + \|\pi(x)\|\|u_0-u\|\\
&\le \frac\varepsilon2 + \|\pi(xx_0^{-1})\|\|\pi(x_0)\|\|u_0-u\|\\
&< \frac\varepsilon2 + C\|\pi(x_0)\| \cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{2C\|\pi(x_0)\|}\\
&= \varepsilon.
\end{align}

Can someone please check whether the statement is true and, if not, where exactly my proof fails?

Comment: I didn't check your proof in detail yet, but note that if your proof is correct then it shows that continuity of $(x,u) \mapsto \pi(x)u$ is **not the same** as continuity of $x \mapsto \pi(x)$, with the toplogy induced by the operator norm on the target space.

Comment: The question you mention is about the continuity of $\pi:G\to L(H)$ where $L(H)$ is endowed with the operator norm. Then continuity at $x_0\in G$ means that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $\sup\{\|\pi(x)v-\pi(x_0)v\|: v\in H,\|v\|\le 1\}<\varepsilon$ for all $x\in U$.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks. It seems that the statement from the question is indeed true but that is still not equivalent to norm continuity.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, I see now that I completely missed the fact that I was actually looking at three different kinds of continuity. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Some of your confusion comes from names. Norm continuity means that the map $G\to B(H)$ is continuous if you equip $B(H)$ with the topology from the  operator norm. This is not the same as $G\times H\to H$, $(g,v)\mapsto \pi(g)v$ being continuous - the first condition is much stronger.

Comment: What is $\|\pi(x_0)\|=0?$

Comment: @QuantumSpace It is not possible. It would mean $\pi(x_0) = 0$ but by definition we have $\pi : G \to \Bbb{B}(H)^\times$ so $\pi(x_0)$ is invertible.

Comment: @mechanodroid Ah of course.